# Excel- Display values from another sheet when a certain value is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have an excel sheet which lists a Project Name in Column A, Start Date in Column D, Launch Date in Column E. The sheet lists a project name multiple times because each row is designated for a specific person assigned to a project. For example, if the Project name is A, the start and launch date will be the same across the board since it's the same project.

On another sheet I'd like to be able to enter a project name and have the values for start and end date pull in from the other sheet so they don't have to be re-typed. To elaborate, if the value entered for the Project Name in the cell is "A" I'd like my column B (Start Date) to pull the start date associated with Project A in the previous sheet (which on this sheet is Column D). The difficulty is there will be multiple instances of Project A on this previous sheet.

What formula should I use?

Comment: If there will be multiple instances, how will you select the correct one (what is the rule)?

Comment: I think he's saying that all the rows on Sheet1 for Project A have the same Start Date and End Date ("the start and launch date will be the same across the board since it's the same project"), which means (1) it doesn't matter which row is referenced by the formula on Sheet2, and (2) the OP's real problem is that he has a badly designed spreadsheet.

Comment: Just use `VLOOKUP()`

Answer (score 0):

this answer the question of what function to use. Assumes that data is on sheet1, and this being entered on sheet2 in columns B&D
=+IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A4,Sheet1!$A$2:D116,COLUMN()),"")